# Can I combine Laravel HTML builder elements: link and image?

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am trying to achieve the following HTML with Laravel HTML builder syntax:

```
<a href='http://icecream.com'><img src='icecream.jpg'></a>
```

How is it done?

This is the image defined using HTML builder

```
{{ HTML::image('icecream.jpg', 'icecream') }}
```

This is the link defined using HTML builder

```
{{ HTML::link('http://icecream.com') }}
```

But I can't figure out how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no builtin solution for this. So, you will have to use plain html for anchor tag.

```
<a href="http://icecream.com">{{ HTML::image("icecream.jpg", "icecream") }}</a>
```

Comment: I think too there's no better solution, as Laravel internally escapes the `$title` argument of `HTML::link()`.

Comment: I think you guys might be right - it is strange because this is a pretty common thing that we have to do.